# Specify timezone in pydantic datetime field [Python]

Tags: python, python-3.x, mongodb, datetime, pydantic

I have a model where i have datetime type fields defined as shown:

```
class DamBaseModel(BaseModel):

    class Config:
        allow_population_by_field_name = True
        use_enum_values = True
        arbitrary_types_allowed = True
        json_encoders = {
            ObjectId: str,
            datetime: lambda d: d.isoformat
        }
```

The defined Model is as follows:

```
class Message(DamBaseModel):
    created_datetime: datetime = Field(default_factory=datetime.now)
```

The data that gets inserted into MongoDb is :

```
{ "created_datetime" : ISODate("2022-08-22T12:02:59.546Z") }
```

But the problem iam currently facing is that the data is received at the client level in this format :

```
{ "created_datetime": "Mon, 22 Aug 2022 12:02:59 GMT" }
```

Iam just fetching the data from the db and projecting it directly without any formatting.
Any help as to how to specify local timezone when projecting the data ??

Comment: I think you need to update your example code because it fails with: `AttributeError: 'builtin_function_or_method' object has no attribute 'isoformat'`. Once it runs successfully you will have higher chances of getting help.

Comment: Could you share the client app code that display the data from the database ?

Answer (score 7):

[Timezone aware timestamps](https://docs.pydantic.dev/latest/usage/validation_errors/#timezone_aware) are now supported in Pydantic V2:

```py
from pydantic import AwareDatetime, TypeAdapter


dt = AwareDatetime
ta = TypeAdapter(dt)

# validate UTC timestamp
ta.validate_python("2022-08-22T12:02:59.546Z")

# Validate timestamp with timezone
ta.validate_python("2022-08-22T12:02:59.546+00:00")
```

Answer (score 5):

I know that this is an old question, but I thought to post an answer for anyone who might stumble upon this thread.

As of now - 22/02/2023 - timezone aware `datetime` is not supported in pydantic.

BUT this feature is in its latest stages of development. Please see bellow links for the latest progress updates:

https://github.com/pydantic/pydantic/discussions/3477#discussioncomment-4017542
https://github.com/pydantic/pydantic/pull/4812

**UPDATE** (26/06/2023)

According to the latest comments in the pull request I mentioned above, this feature will not be available until Pydantic v2 comes out.