# Pandas does not preserve datetime type when converting pydantic objects to dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, pydantic

I've migrated my code to pydantic V2 and found an unexpected behaviour when working with pydantic objects (timezone-aware timestamps/datetimes) and pandas. I have a list of pydantic objects and I have to convert it to pandas DataFrame. When you run the code below, it should work in both versions of pydantic (v1 and v2). But the final DataFrame in v2 does not preserve the original data type.

**Example code:**

```py
import pandas as pd
from datetime import datetime
from pydantic import BaseModel


class MyModel(BaseModel):
    ts: datetime


m1 = MyModel(ts="2023-07-01T10:00:00Z")
m2 = MyModel(ts="2023-07-02T10:00:00Z")

# note: dict is used here instead of newer model_dump so this example runs in V1 as well
d1 = pd.DataFrame([m1.dict()])
d2 = pd.DataFrame([m2.dict()])

df_concat = pd.concat([d1, d2])
```

When you run it with pydantic v1, `df_concat` preserve the correct datatype (`ts    datetime64[ns, UTC]`), but using v2, the output datatype is just `object`.

It seems it relates to some change in timezone handling, because in pydantic v1 we get `tzinfo=datetime.timezone.utc` but in v2 `tzinfo=TzInfo(UTC)`. And pandas probably cannot handle it correctly. Is this a bug (on either side - pydantic or pandas) or should I do sth differently?

I could convert all `tzinfo` to use the `datetime.timezone.utc` (like  `m1.ts.replace(tzinfo=datetime.timezone.utc)`) and then I will get the expected behavior (correct data types), but it's not much conveniant way how to do it. I would rather find a way how to preserve the original behavior that was in v1.

[Pydantic issue reference](https://github.com/pydantic/pydantic/issues/6592)

Comment: you should be able to supply a pandas type; `ts=pd.Timestamp("2023-07-01T10:00:00Z")` - not sure however if that works with pydantic v1.

Comment: Does using `AwareDatetime` solve this for you? https://stackoverflow.com/a/76700426/10521959

Comment: @YaakovBressler `AwareDatetime` does not help me, it has the same behaviour (`tzinfo=TzInfo(UTC)`) which does not preserve datetime type when doing the concatenation.

Comment: @FObersteiner Supplying directly pandas type helps, but the real code (not the simplified example in tmy question) already reads data from elsewhere and I would need to do the conversion (either in model or later in the dataframe). The issue is that I would like to find a way that would preserve the behaviour between v1 and v2 without doing additional conversions (e.g. by providing some config to pydantic model or so).